# How do you pass as a template template parameter a variadic alias template nested within a class template that is instantiated via a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-templates

I hope the following example is less convoluted than the title!

Suppose we have a few metafunctions; a `Trait`, `ReversePartial` which binds the types in a parameter pack to the back of a variadic class template, and a `Test` sink which accepts the resulting alias template.

```cpp
template<typename, typename...>
struct Trait : std::true_type {};

template<template<typename...> typename Template, typename... Ts>
struct ReversePartial
{
    template<typename... Us>
    using Apply = Template<Us..., Ts...>;
};

template<template<typename...> typename>
struct Test {};
```

Why are we able to compile when explicitly specifying the types to be applied

```cpp
using T = Test<ReversePartial<Trait, int, double>::Apply>; // compiles
```

but not when passing them via a parameter pack?

```cpp
error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template

template<typename... Ts>
using U = Test<ReversePartial<Trait, Ts...>::Apply>; // does not compile
```

Is there a workaround to achieve this?

[Try on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WjTFJc)

Comment: `using U = Test<ReversePartial<Trait, Ts...>::template Apply>;`?

Comment: @appleapple - IMHO, you should expand your comment in an answer.

Comment: @max66 I'm just writing answer and this Q is closed :/

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn I tried that earlier. My bad! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @appleapple - sorry: I didn't noticed it.